# Azure Pipelines - Code keeps going under wwwroot/s instead of wwwroot

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - "*"

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: BuildAndPublish
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndPublishJob
    displayName: 'Build and Publish'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.x'
        checkLatest: true

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build:dev
      displayName: 'Build React App'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        artifact: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- stage: DeployFunctionApp
  displayName: 'Deploy Function App'
  dependsOn: BuildAndPublish
  jobs:
  - job: DeployFunctionAppJob
    displayName: 'Deploy Function App'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: 'Download Artifact'
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
        appName: $(webAppName)
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
        deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
        appType: 'webApp'
        appSettings: '-appServicePlan $(appServicePlan)'
```

I'm trying to publish a app service to azure with this pipeline. The pipeline runs successfully, but I get a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error when accessing the page. After looking at the site on kudo, I noticed that all the code is under the source directory wwwroot/s instead of wwwroot. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying one React app via Azure DevOps pipeline and it was successful:-

I have used Nodejs react template like below:-

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:

 
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxa86d831'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'siliconwebapp655'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapp655'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|18.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

In order to resolve this error, Refer my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412290/not-able-to-access-azure-webapp-url/76414671#76414671) on the same issue.

Your React application is placed in output directory build:dev but the Build Artifact is not saved to the drop folder correctly, Make sure your drop folder has correct zip file uploaded.

You can modify your pipeline like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - "*"

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: BuildAndPublish
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndPublishJob
    displayName: 'Build and Publish'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.x'
        checkLatest: true

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build:dev
        echo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        ls $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build:dev # Verify that the build output exists
      displayName: 'Build React App'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        artifact: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
        targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build:dev' # Publish the build output

- stage: DeployFunctionApp
  displayName: 'Deploy Function App'
  dependsOn: BuildAndPublish
  jobs:
  - job: DeployFunctionAppJob
    displayName: 'Deploy Function App'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: 'Download Artifact'
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
        
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
        appName: $(webAppName)
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/build:dev' # Set the deployment package path to the build output
        deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
        appType: 'webApp'
        appSettings: '-appServicePlan $(appServicePlan)'
```

Make sure your Build.SourcesDirectory includes your code file correctly.

Also, Check if your repository file structure is correct. My Azure Repo React file structure:-

[image]

I tried accessing my folder via Kudu tool and my wwwroot file looked like below:-

```bash
ls
cd site
cd wwwroot
ls
```

[image]

[image]